# How can I find the greater then and less then date with the available date

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

As you show in the below images I want to fetch result in between date from date range.

I have try this query but it doesn't work.

I want bigger date then DTT_EVT_start start table date.

Can anyone suggest me how can I use date(not time)column in where clause ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM `dwssgv_esp_datetime` 
WHERE (DATE_FORMAT(DTT_EVT_start, '%Y-%m-%d') < '2015-05-10') 
  AND (DATE_FORMAT(DTT_EVT_end, '%Y-%m-%d') > '2015-05-10')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid DATE_FORMAT function, 
as it would affect on the performance if its a huge table

you may simply do like,

```
    SELECT 
            * 
    FROM 
            dwssgv_esp_datetime 
    WHERE 
            DTT_EVT_start <  CAST('2015-05-10 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) AND 
            DTT_EVT_end   >  CAST('2015-05-10 00:00:00' AS DATETIME)
```

Here, < 2015-05-10 > is your variable date.

OR

```
    SELECT 
            * 
    FROM 
            dwssgv_esp_datetime 
    WHERE 
            DATE(DTT_EVT_start) <  CAST('2015-05-10' AS DATE) AND 
            DATE(DTT_EVT_end)   >  CAST('2015-05-10' AS DATE)
```

Comment: is it possible to enter only date not time ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM dwssgv_esp_datetime WHERE DTT_EVT_start < '2015-05-10' AND DTT_EVT_end > ''2015-05-10'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert dates in UNIX_TIMESTAMP format and compare

Try this

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
   `dwssgv_esp_datetime` 
WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DTT_EVT_start) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-05-10') 
AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DTT_EVT_end) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-05-10')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM dwssgv_esp_datetime 
WHERE 
     CAST('2015-05-10' AS DATE)
     BETWEEN  DATE(DTT_EVT_start)
     AND DATE(DTT_EVT_end)
```

`BETWEEN AND` allows you to check if a value is in a particular range or not. By using this you do not have to write the value you want to compare twice.